# Fabric cannot import module in function

Tags: python, import, module, fabric

This is an extract from my fabric script

```
def create_php_site(name):
    """
    Creates a new php installation
    """

    from resource.php.git import gitignore
    from resource.php.nginx import nginx
```

when I run it, I get error "ImportError: No module named php.git"

but if I move "from resource.php.git import gitignore " outside of the function, it works. Any ideas?
Each layer of resource.php.git has `__init__.py`

There is git.py in resource/php/:

```
gitignore = """.DS_Store
._.DS_Store
"""
```

Comment: What's in your resource/php/git directory? Is it actually a python module?

Comment: Yes it is actually a python module.

Comment: So in git.py, what is gitignore?

Comment: I have created a new project with your directory structure and works for me.

Comment: yeah it's very strange, I think it's because of fabric...

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a namespace conflict.

You *cannot* name your directory `resource` because there's a standard python module named `resource` - http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html

And so when you declare `from resource...` all hell breaks loose. Python cannot find `php.git` because indeed, in the standard `resource` python module, there's no such functionalities.

I created a similar example but instead renamed `resource` directory to `myresource`. Performing the imports then work perfectly. Like this:-

```
>>> from myresource.php.git import gitignore
>>> gitignore
'my ignore strings'
```

**IMPORTANT**

Please also make sure that you have an `__init__.py` file in your `myresource` directory.

Comment: Yup. Since your `git.py` is in `resource/php/nginx` directory, you need to do `from resource.php.nginx.git import gitignore`.

Comment: And you also have a `git` directory in `resource/php`? If that's the case, you are having a name space conflict. you should rename either your `git.py` file to something else or `git` directory (containing its own `__init__` file) to something else.

Comment: not git directory in resource/php/, just git.py and `__init__.py`

Comment: Ok, figured it out. You have a namespace conflict with a standard python module. Answer updated.

Comment: but I have tried renaming resource just to res and still had issue. I think it's due to fabric

Comment: Having a directory name `res` works for me as well. Is it a different error now?  If so, can you share the error message? Is your "res" directory residing in `PYTHONPATH`. `import sys; sys.path` to see the list of directories in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Try this - in your terminal, cd to the directory where your `res` directory is located. If you `res` directory is located in `/Users/james/work/`, then `cd /Users/james/work`.  At this location, launch your python shell with `python`. Now attempt the import: `from res.php.git import gitignore`.

Comment: Also - this is very important - please make sure that you have an `__init__.py` file in your `res` directory.

Comment: yes first thing I double checked was `__init__.py` in every folder level.

Comment: Have you tried to emulate this problem in python shell per my step-by-step above?

Comment: There is no problem importing the module form the top of the file, the problem is a result of combination of using fabric and importing within a function

Comment: Then that is a `PYTHONPATH` problem.  The question you need to answer is - is your "res" module located in `PYTHONPATH`? If it is, it will be **exactly** the same as the import you perform from "the top of the file".

Comment: res is not specifically in PYTHONPATH, but in the same project

Comment: Can you share the folder structure (of your full project, containing `res`) in your question above? If it's in the "same project", how do you import other modules in this project? This has implications on how we write our import statements.

Comment: If you are using Linux/Unix, use 'tree' to help render directory structure in terminal and copy and paste! :-)

Comment: I have made a lot of changes and refactored a lot of things to make this work(time constraint)... so I am unable to give the tree structure it was before... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok. Cool. So what was the problem? `PYTHONPATH` problem inside your project directories?

Comment: No, I couldn't resolve that issue, so I splited main code into different modules and import those modules at the top.